# Is subdivision of hindusim mentioned anywhere in vedas?

Tags: vedas

I am curious on how sub sections in religion are created, for example I am from TamilNadu and there are so many divisions like in Brahmin - Iyer has vadama, vathima brahacharanam and iyengar has thenkalai vadakalai and so many others. Are all these defined somewhere in vedas?

As for as I am aware, the division is based on the rishi one's ancestor followed as we detail it in the अभिवादये .  I am newbie, please excuse if I miss any basic concepts.

Comment: They are divisions based on Sampradaya which a person follows. It has nothing to do with Vedas.